# Why can't I use `predict` inside a data.table?

Tags: r, data.table, predict

I'm trying to use predict.lm inside data.table, and getting a strange error. The first part, data-prep, runs perfectly.

```
# (1) Load data
library(data.table)
homeprice = fread('https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/mosaicData/SaratogaHouses.csv')

# (2) Data Prep: Convert character variables into factors.
myvars = c('heating','fuel','sewer','waterfront','newConstruction','centralAir')
for (var in myvars) {
   homeprice[, paste0(var) := as.factor(get(var))]
}

# (3) Split data into training and test sets
install.packages('caTools')
library(caTools)

homeprice[, split := sample.split(V1, SplitRatio = 0.5)]
train = homeprice[split == T,] # Creating training data
test = homeprice[split == F,] # Create test data


# Train OLS model with training data.
reg1 = lm(price ~ . - V1, train)
summary(reg1) # Displays the results from "myfirstreg"
```

OK, here is the part that's giving me trouble:

```
# In sample-prediction: Predict prices for training set
z = predict(reg1, newdata = train)
train[, price_pred := z] # Works perfectly
train[, price_pred := predict(reg1, newdata = train)] # Gives error
```

Please advise.

Comment: Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : 
  invalid 'envir' argument of type 'logical'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appear that the presence of the "split" variable, which was used to split the original dataset, was giving problems. Removing it from the regression appears to solve the issue.

```
reg1 = lm(price ~ . - V1 - split, train)
```

Comment: maybe try something like `train[, price_pred := predict(reg1, newdata=.SD), .SDcols=-"split"]`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what causes the error but using `dplyr`

```
train <- train %>% 
  mutate(price_pred = predict(reg1, newdata = train))
```

seems to give the same results as your exapmle that does work.